# How do we store cascading taxes in a database? or database structure for storing taxes

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, database-design

Hi i have to create a database structure for storing tax details.

I have an `itemDetails` table which has the details of the item like name and price.

The problem is for each item there are two taxes service charge (10%) and VAT (4%)
but the taxes are cascaded i.e after I apply servicecharge, then on the new total I have to apply I apply vat.

I want to store this in a database; I can acheive this with hard coding it but I want it in a database so that in the future if the customer wants he can store more taxes by specifying which order the taxes apply and weather they cascade or not. And each item may have a different tax structure.. (Ex. one item may have the above mentioned tax structure, another item has only vat, another item has a completely diffenet structure etc)

I have a tax category table where the user can store a tax structure and each item will belong to a tax category i.e the `itemDetailsTable` has `TaxCategory_id` in it. I need your help figuring it out from there.

Comment: Store the "type" of tax (I would store the specific type and not a category) and then apply a formula programatically (let this be *free* of the data-model) -- either in your program or in a stored procedure, etc. The computed value *may* be stored for historical-at-computed-time purposes, although such a choice should be looked at in relationship with the business requirements (e.g. what happens if the formula to changes?)

Answer (score 1):

You could add another table that has a many-to-one relationship with TaxCategory that uses a ranking column to define what order the taxes are applied in.

```
TaxCategoryRates

taxCategoryId    taxRate    taxRank   taxDescription
-------------    -------    -------   --------------
1                10         1         Service Charge
1                4          2         VAT
2                3          NULL      Local Sales Tax
2                4.5        NULL      State Sales Tax
```

Your logic then applies the taxes in order of taxRank.  If you have other tax categories where order doesn't matter (as in taxCategoryId 2), you can just leave the rank NULL and have your logic sum the tax rates and apply them.